# Database connectivity error in my Swing application as cast to statement

Tags: java, mysql, swing, compiler-errors

This is my code. I am getting error as cast to statement in the statement line:

```
Statement st=null;
Connection con=null;

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb","root","");

st=(Statement) con.createStatement();
```

How to overcome this?

Comment: yeah its working @peeskillet:) i removed the import of java.beans.statement

Answer (score 0):

createStatement method will return Object of Statement class, so you don't need to do type casting.

I think error is in **st.("insert into ");** line.
You have to use **execute** or **executeQuery** method of Statement class.

For Ex: `st.execute("Your query here");`

Comment: my question is when i type
Statement st=null;
.
.
st.createStatement();

its showing like cast the create statement to statement and the line is changed to 
st=(Statement) con.createStatement();

Comment: Which IDE are you using? i.e. Eclipse or Netbeans or something else

Comment: net beans. i cleared my problem i deleted the import of java.beans.statement package